# ng-repeat is commened in the browser Element section in AngularJs?

Tags: angularjs, firebase

I have to call the firebase function for get the sellerProducts but in my case function is called peoperly and array is display in the element console but ng-repeat data is commented what is the problem in my code?

```js
//FUNCTION FOR GET THE LIST OF PRODUCT'S
$scope.productArray   = []; 
 $scope.getProductData = function() {               
  firebase.database().ref("sellerProduct").once('value').
       then(function(snapshot) {
          var value = snapshot.val();
         $scope.productArray = objToArray(value);
      });
     }
 $scope.getProductData();
```

```html
<div class="productInfo  w3-col m3  w3-card-4 w3-margin-left"  
ng-repeat="list in filtered  = (productArray | filter: product) | filter:brandFilter">
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: by simply `ng-repeat="list in filtered"` it works right?

Comment: thank you sir its working but what's the wrong in my code i have requirment of the filtered variable?

Comment: I believe this is causing you a syntax error in `ng-repeat` `= (productArray | filter: product)`. Where did `product` come from and why there is assignment. Though refer to my answer for a better way of implementing this

Comment: Sir i am using (filter :product)  for search product from input field that's  the reason i am using ?sir i have requirement of both the filtered as well as productArray in the ng-repeat?

Comment: in the `onchange` of the filter product call `$scope.filterByBrand` in my example. OR do `ng-repeat="item in productArray | filter: product"`

Comment: ok sir i will try this

Answer (score 1):

As far as I could suggest it is much better to `NOT` use ng-filter at all inside a `ng-repeat` as it will cost you severe performance issue later on.

so instead of doing this:

```
ng-repeat="list in filtered  = (productArray | filter: product) | filter:brandFilter"
```

just simply use:

```
ng-repeat="list in productArray"
```

then in your JS code format the array first the way you wanted it to be displayed, before assigning it to `$scope.productArray`

```
.then(function(snapshot)
{
      var value = snapshot.val();
      // save the original array
      $scope.productArrayOrig = angular.copy(objToArray(value));
      $scope.productArray = $scope.filterByBrand();
  });
});

// then just create a function that filters your projectData by brandFilter
$scope.filterByBrand = function ()
{
    var finalData = [];

    if ($scope.productArrayOrig)
    {
        // then loop it
        for (var i = 0; i < $scope.productArrayOrig.length; i++)
        {
            var item = $scope.productArrayOrig[i];

            if ($scope.brandFilter == item["brand"])
            {
                finalData.push(item);
            }
        }
    }

    return finalData;
};
```

hope that helps